# Is there a way to automate NACHA batch file payments to banks from a generated NACHA file?

Tags: node.js, payment

Is there a way to automate NACHA batch file payments to banks from a generated NACHA file?

I want to get customers bank info into a system then take that info and generate payments to

my account with a batch file.

How can this be done with node.js??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

I've open sourced an ACH file generation library called nACH2

https://github.com/glenselle/nACH2

---

This has been a while, but for anyone interested, there is an NPM module called [nacha](https://github.com/bitfloor/nacha) that does what you want. It was made by Bitfloor, the Bitcoin exchange company who recently closed their doors after they were hacked. It's still on their ghostly Github account and I contacted the the man who wrote it. He said he had used it in production for several months without problems. But...he would advise that some work be put in to adding more tests, making the module more extensible and just testing it to be sure it is generating the correct files. I've taken a look at it, and I might attempt to re-write the NPM module for the company I'm working for and then open source it so others can benefit. In the meantime, you could take a look at that NPM module for generating ACH NACHA files.

Comment: People like you make the world go round. Quick question: are all the fields in all three steps you listed in your readme (nach.File({}), nach.Batch({}), nach.Entry({})) required to create the ach file? Which fields are the absolute minimum requirements?

Comment: In answer to first question, yes. ACH is a terrible format & system. You really need to know the file requirements for the financial institution you intend to work with. Different institutions use different software which expects the file to be formatted differently. They will often have a PDF guide with what they expect. But at a minimum, files have batches with entries contained within them. Beyond that, there could be any number of variations...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I’ll be able to pass your libs instructions to the bank we’re going to work with and ask them what info they’d require. Will your lib go ahead and create the files regardless of what fields are filled in/left blank? Ie does it require all fields to generate the nacha file

Comment: It tries to follow general best practices and enforce only those fields which are required. If it has a required field that you don't need, you can ask your partner bank if it's ok to "pad" it with zeros. With flat files like those used in ACH, you can usually just fill unused fields with zeros if there's no relevant data

Comment: Got it. Do you have a list of those base required fields you’re mentioning? I didn’t see it in the readme

Comment: Can we use nacha module automatically without any problem

Answer (score 3):

Any of us that have worked with multiple data formats and are familiar with the NACHA (or ACH) file format know that it is awful.  It is a fixed width file that is inconsistent from row to row and nearly impossible to work with.  Banks in the United States are required to utilize this format with organizations like Federal Reserve, but technically savvy banks will not require that format from their customers.

You might ask your bank if they accept file formats other than NACHA formatted files.  For example, our bank accepts NACHA, XML, EDI820, ISO20022, .CSV, fixed width, and delimited files that are much easier to work with.  We also provide information back to systems regarding the status of those payments after they are initiated.

Regarding the automation piece, absolutely.  Files can be automatically encrypted with PGP, transmitted via SFTP.  Likewise, some banks will also deliver files to you via SFTP or have a server where you can pick the data up.  There are many free open source applications that can help you accomplish this  WinSCP and Cleopatra are two widely used applications that will keep the data secure and get it where it needs to go.

If your banker is not able to help you with these functions or you are looking for a technically savvy bank, please feel free to give our Treasury Management department a call at 913-563-5600 and ask them to schedule a technical call with the IT staff and we can help point your team in the right direction.